# Undefined Error messages on Copy URL to Clipboard scripts

Tags: jquery, undefined

I've been trying to locate a script to have a button Copy a URL to the Clipboard. There's a bunch but none seem to actually work and deliver errors. I found one on GitHub and I thought this might be it, but it's throwing an not defined error on the final line of code saying the Copy is not defined: Here's that code:

```
var CombleURL = "";
jQuery('a.btn-copy').each(function () {
    var theLinkElement = jQuery(this);
    if (theLinkElement.text().includes('mkv')) {
        CombleURL = CombleURL + theLinkElement.attr('href') + " \r";
    }
}
);
copy(CombleURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Bell, If you are getting an undefined error, that could be because you haven't define a function called copy using function expression or function declarations.